# Host Custom Controls using Windows Ribbon Framework

Tags: winapi, controls, ribbon, windows-ribbon-framework

Does anybody know if it's possible to host custom controls within the Ribbon bar when using the native Windows Ribbon Framework (the one introduced with Windows 7, used in MS Paint / Wordpad for example, NOT the Office Ribbon Framework)?

I know of the available controls as listed at the following MSDN source but I'd like to know if it's possible to use my own controls too.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940497(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have experienced so far this is not possible. Neither got an answer here, nor in the Microsoft Partner forums.

Marking as solved.

Comment: Thats why you can license a few Look&Feel clones from 3rd party vendors.